# How do you progress through the Google add-on authorization lifecycle?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I feel like a bit of an idiot asking this question, but how do you actually move up from AuthMode.NONE to AuthMode.LIMITED to AuthMode.FULL?

I have https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets in required scopes and this code:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  if (e.authMode === ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE) {
    ui
    .createAddonMenu()
    .addItem('Authorise', 'authorise')
    .addToUi();
  } else {
    // This never runs
  }
}

function authorise() {
  ui.alert(ScriptApp.AuthMode);
}
```

When testing the addon in AuthMode.NONE, the menu item appears. Clicking it brings up an authorisation request, but then AuthMode remains NONE. What is the correct structure to get to LIMITED? And beyond that, how do you get to FULL?

I've read the [authorization lifecycle docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/lifecycle) a hundred times, but it fails to explain this very simple point fully.

Thank you!

Comment: The AuthMode is determined by conditions, and the only way to change the conditions is by saving a new test configuration, or testing a live published version under different conditions.   AuthMode.NONE only happens in "installed" mode, not installed and enabled. In the "test as add-on" dialog box for configuring an add-on test, there is a drop down for INSTALLATION CONFIG.  If you change the setting, you'll see the "Test in" link change to show the auth mode.

Comment: @pnuts, Web Applications is for 'expert and advanced users of web applications.' It states: 'Creating or developing web applications' is off-topic.

Comment: Thanks @SandyGood - I'm still struggling though. Are you basically saying that AuthMode will not actually change during a test? I have to rerun the test in multiple AuthMode states?

Comment: In test mode the AuthMode won't change.  The AuthMode will only change when using a published version.

Comment: Thank you @Sandy - I think that was my major confusion! I'm still not sure how you get to FULL though?

Comment: The simple trigger designated by the reserved function name `onOpen()` *never* runs in AuthMode.FULL.  One of the most common problems that people have, is wondering why their code won't work inside a simple trigger.  A simple trigger is basically "Read Only" access.